# Background rectangle over preformatted text on a QTextEdit?

Tags: html, qt

I want to show some preformated text (`<pre></pre>`) tags. and that text to be shown in side a colored rectangle. Can I do that using html in a QTextEdit? If so how? Because the html answers I found use CSS but Qt does not seem to recognize the style atrribute? (According to the documentation at least, it shouldn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting

```
<pre style=\"background-color:red\">textline\ntextline 2</pre>
```

in a QPlainTextEdit using `appendHtml` leads to this:

[image: screenshot]

`QTextEdit` doesn't have an `appendHtml` slot, so if you cannot use `QPlainTextEdit` you might have to look into RichText format that Qt uses (not to be confused with RTF).